# Vectorize an index-based matrix operation in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

How can I vectorize the following loop?

```
def my_fnc():
   m = np.arange(27.).reshape((3,3,3))
   ret = np.empty_like(m)

   it = np.nditer(m, flags=['multi_index'])
   for x in it:
      i,j,k = it.multi_index
      ret[i,j,k] = x / m[i,j,i]
   return ret
```

Basically I'm dividing each value in m by something *similar* to a diagonal. Not all values in m will be different, the arange is just an example.

*Thanks in advance!* ~

**P.S.:** here's the output of the function above, don't mind the nans :)

```
array([[[        nan,         inf,         inf],
        [ 1.        ,  1.33333333,  1.66666667],
        [ 1.        ,  1.16666667,  1.33333333]],

       [[ 0.9       ,  1.        ,  1.1       ],
        [ 0.92307692,  1.        ,  1.07692308],
        [ 0.9375    ,  1.        ,  1.0625    ]],

       [[ 0.9       ,  0.95      ,  1.        ],
        [ 0.91304348,  0.95652174,  1.        ],
        [ 0.92307692,  0.96153846,  1.        ]]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`advanced-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) to get the `m[i,j,i]` equivalent in one go and then simply divide input array by it -

```
r = np.arange(len(m))
ret = m/m[r,:,r,None] # Add new axis with None to allow for broadcasting
```

Comment: Ah, that's clever! Thanks :D